# Greedy Algorithm

Tags: javascript, greedy

I am writing a piece of code, when a user enters the amount of change owed, returns the minimum amount of coins to equal that change. For instance, assuming only quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies are used. You enter $1.00. The number my code will render on the screen is 4 (4 quarters equaling a dollar). However, I am experiencing a small bug. If you type in $0.41 for example, you'd expect the code to render 4 again (1 quarter + 1 dime + 1 nickel + 1 penny is the minimum amount of permutations to equal 41 cents), but it doesn't, it renders 5.44. Please help! Thank you in advance.

```js
document.write("Hi,how much change is due? ");

function greed () {
 
 var n = document.getElementById('change').value;
 
 if (n >=0)
 { 
  
 
  function amount (amt){
   
    return amt/25 + (amt%25)/10 + ((amt%25)%10)/5 + ((amt%25)%10)%5;
    
    }
  document.write(amount(Math.round(n*100)));
 }
 else {alert("Invalid Amount!")};
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">

 <head>

  <title>Greedy! </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="greedy.js" ></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <form>
   <fieldset>
    <input type="number" id="change" name="change" value="0"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="greed();"/>
  
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: and if you write 0.1 it returns 1.4. You're missing something very important there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you're not treating the numbers as integers, so you get decimal numbers everywhere. Let's use your example (0.41):

`amt = n*100 = 41`, so let's go to the return:

```
return amt/25 + (amt%25)/10 + ((amt%25)%10)/5 + ((amt%25)%10)%5
```

which is the same as

```
return 41/25 + (41%25)/10 + ((41%25)%10)/5 + ((41%25)%10)%5
```

as you know, `41/25 =/= 1`, same with `(41%25)/10 = 16/10 =/= 1` and `((41%25)%10)/5 = (16%10)/5 = 6/5 =/= 1`, but you don't care about that in the code so you end up adding those decimal numbers till the end, and get weird values.

You must use `parseInt()` to get Integer values, so it should look like this:

```
return parseInt(amt/25) + parseInt((amt%25)/10) + parseInt(((amt%25)%10)/5) + ((amt%25)%10)%5
```

To show it works:

```js
document.write("Hi,how much change is due? ");

function greed () {
 
 var n = document.getElementById('change').value;
 
 if (n >=0)
 { 
  
 
  function amount (amt){
   
    return parseInt(amt/25) + parseInt((amt%25)/10) + parseInt(((amt%25)%10)/5) + ((amt%25)%10)%5;
    
    }
  document.write(amount(Math.round(n*100)));
 }
 else {alert("Invalid Amount!")};
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">

 <head>

  <title>Greedy! </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="greedy.js" ></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <form>
   <fieldset>
    <input type="number" id="change" name="change" value="0"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="greed();"/>
  
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is parseInt() used rather than Math.floor() ?

Comment: to be honest, here both will have the same effect so you can use any, I'm just used to `parseInt()`. In reality, `Math.floor()` is a lot faster so it's actually better, even though you won't notice in just 3 operations.